# Residue of $\frac{z}{\cosh(1/z)}$ at $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I need the

> residue of
>   $$\dfrac{z}{\cosh(\frac{1}{z})}$$
>   in the origin $z=0$.

I tried expanding the hyperbolic function and writing it as a converging infinite sum:
$$\frac{z}{\cosh(\frac{1}{z})}=\frac{z}{1+\frac{1}{2!} \frac{1}{z^2}+\frac{1}{4!} \frac{1}{z^4}+...} = z \cdot \frac{1}{1-(-\frac{1}{2!}\frac{1}{z^2}-\frac{1}{4!}\frac{1}{z^4}-...)}$$

However, since we're looking at a point near the origin $z=0$, the term between brackets diverges and the fraction can't be written as a sum of powers of $\dfrac{1}{z}$, so I can't find the coefficient for $\dfrac{1}{z}$.

How do I compute the series expansion by hand?

Comment: Maybe some Taylor expansion of $1/z$ can help to embedd $1/\cosh(\frac 1 z )$ in

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that $0$ is not an [isolated singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolated_singularity) for   $f(z)=\frac{z}{\cosh(\frac{1}{z})}$ because 
$$\cosh(1/z_k)=0\quad\mbox{for}\quad z_k=\frac{i}{(k+1/2)\pi} \quad\mbox{and}\quad \lim_{k\to \infty}z_k=0.$$
Hence $f$ has not a Laurent series expansion at $z=0$  and the residue is not defined at $z=0$.

Comment: Oh I knew that, but I forgot that that meant that it doesn't have a Laurent series. So the question becomes, how do I calculate the residue of a function in 0 that has no Laurent series near 0? Most importantly: can it be done without calculating the Laurent coefficients explicitly using the integral form?

Comment: Elaborating on this, what does this mean for the integral $\oint_{∂B(0,1/π)}\frac{z}{cosh(\frac{1}{z})}dz$ ? The points $z_k$ you mentioned are poles I believe. So this would become: $2πi\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} $Res$_{z_k}$ where k=0 is omitted because it isn't inside the contour, and z=0 doesn't have any effect?

Comment: Yes, the final result should be $i(32-\pi^3)/\pi^2$

Answer (score 2):

$$\text{Res}\left(\frac{z}{\cosh \left(\frac{1}{z}\right)},\{z,0\}\right)=\int_0^{2 \pi } \frac{e^{i t}}{\cosh \left(\frac{1}{e^{i t}}\right)} \, dt=0$$

There is no residue at $z=0$

The best I could do with series is to get a non convergent series $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } (2 n)! z^{2 n+1}$ which shows that there is no residue at $z=0$ because it is not a pole.

Hope this helps

Comment: The RHS is the expansion of $z\cdot \cosh(\frac{1}{z})$

Comment: @RobertZ Thank you! I realized just a moment after clicking the button :)